# How to perform operations upon a WCF service creation?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ria

I have an integration test suite in silverlight that requires an http server and a socket server.
What I've been thinking to do is to control the suite from silverlight through a WCF RIA service.
I would like to know how to start those servers (They are already coded in c# and can be run seperately) whenever the WCF service starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the WCF service is hosted in IIS ASP.NET, you can use Application_Start in Global.asax to trigger starting the other services.

If you host the WCF service in a console app or Windows service, then of course that is where you would call the code to start up those external services.